# Magento 2 - How to use jQuery in a template?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, jquery

I tried to use jQuery in a template (*app\code\Black\Newsletter2Go\view\frontend\templates\account\dashboard\info.phtml*) but I get **jQuery is not defined**.

Does Magento 2 not use jQuery?

Do I have to add:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to the head template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add jquery in head, You can add like below method in phtml

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ],function($) {
         $(document).ready(function() {
            /* Your logic */
         });  
     });
</script>
```

Comment: But this does use jquery 1